# Change month names that are returned from ToString("MMMM") to own names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

With following code I get the following result in de-CH culture:

```
var dateFormat = new DateTime(2016, 10, 12).ToString("MMMM");
//Oktober
```

Though what I really want is "Oktobär" because I am translating into a dialect.

Can I override which month names are returned in de-CH culture? The names that it returns for other cultures should stay the same.

Comment: Swiss german has no official spelling rules. Therefore you can't achieve that by changing it to the de-CH culture.

Comment: @diiN_ Yes, I know that.

Comment: You can change it for one specific instance of `CultureInfo` (see `DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`) but that won't change what happens if you fetch the `de-CH` culture again. Are you always using that specific culture? If so, you can just pass it into all the `ToString`/`Format` calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CultureInfo myCIclone = new CultureInfo("de-CH");

myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = new string[]
{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","Oktobär","11","12", "13"};

var dateFormat = new DateTime(2016, 10, 12).ToString("MMMM", myCIclone);
```

You can override the MonthNames like John Skeet mentioned, for specific culture info.

Comment: And if you set the modified culture on the current thread, you don't need to specify it as as second parameter of the `ToString` method.

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected! I read this in the documentation about DateTimeFormat.MonthNames: `If you set the MonthNames property, you must also set the MonthGenitiveNames property.` What will these be used for? I don't understand the remark that is added in the MonthGenetiveNames property: `In some languages, a month name that is part of a date appears in the genitive case. For example, a date in the Russian (Russia) or "ru-RU", culture consists of the day number and the genitive month name, such as 1 Января.`

Comment: @Marimba from what I understand this is for grammatical case of the language. Most cyrillic languages have this, that means depending on the context the month name will be different. So if your language has genitive language case you should override it too.

Comment: @mybirthname Ah. Now I get this!

Answer (score 0):

This may be help full to you. You need to override the default value.

```
//Declare Culture Info with your goblaization name.
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-CH");

//Assign needed value.
culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","Oktobär","11","12", "13"};

//Assign it in string.
string date= new DateTime(2016, 10, 12).ToString("MMMM", culture);
```